# Print data from Python dictionary based on variable?

Tags: python

Im trying to write a simple script that makes a game run on a single processor core, as ive heard it doesnt work very well with multicore processors.This script chooses a random core and fires up the game, id like it to tell me which core its starting up on. Rcore chooses a random int from cores and uses that as the system command to start up the game.
decore is the dictionary that translates the "binary" back into human langauge. ex

```
core1 = 1
core2 = 2
core3 = 4
core4 = 8
```

Id like to print the core its chosen in the command prompt before starting the game, i cant figure out how to do that.

```
from os import system as sysc
import random
cores = [1,2,4,8]
rcore = int(random.choice(cores))
data = "\"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k start \"\" /affinity %s \"C:\Program Files     (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Kerbal Space Program\KSP.exe\"" %rcore
decore ={ 1:'1',2 :'2',4 :'3',8:'4'}

print 'Launching KSP on processor core:%s'
sysc('%s'%(data))
```

Heres what i tried

```
>>> for rcore in decore:
...     print rcore
8
1
2
4
```

..Not the result i wanted. Is there an easy, magic way to do this? The script does work, it works very well..it just doesnt display what i want.

Comment: im not using threading....the script is used to start the windows command prompt which sets the affinity in the task manager.. Python is only used to start cmd with the right "string"

Comment: @Martijn: I don't think this is a threading question; the launched program isn't even a python program.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Ah, indeed; this is trying to use Python to start another unrelated program and assign it to a random core. Check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you want to use `decore[rcore]` to read the value of rcore from dictionary decore.

However, as has already been suggested to you, use of processor affinities may not be the best way for you to go forward. This is because rather than processors, what you are seeing is cores, and task migration between cores will not hurt your application much with cache misses. Processor affinity on the other hand could prevent quicker scheduling for your process and hence degrade performance.

Comment: worked perfectly! theres the python magic i was looking for, thank you good sir, i will remember that for always

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for rcore in decore:
...     print decore[rcore]
```

Answer (score 0):

And the simple extension to what you were working on earlier:

for core in cores:
    print decore[core]

1
2
3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, because the question's a little unclear IMO, but I think you're looking for

```
decore={1:'1',2 :'2',4 :'3',8:'4'}

for rcore in decore.values():
    print rcore
```

which should give

```
4
1
2
3
```

decore.keys() gives a list [1,2,4,8] and decore.values() gives the list ['1','2','3','4'].

Additionally, decore[rcore] will give you the string with that core value, which can be displayed like this:

```
print 'Launching KSP on processor core:%s' % decore[rcore]
sysc(data)
```